# cs cart file paths

Tags: php, cs-cart

I am doing a redesign on a cs cart.  I copied all the clients files to my server and copied the clients database info also.  I created the database and changed the correct info in the config.php file.  The index page and some other pages load correctly, but I can't link to the store items as it returns a 404.  I have no idea what to do to make the rest of the linking work properly.  Has anyone else had issues with cs cart like this?  Also, the client has an old crappy version from 2007.

Comment: What is a CS cart? Commerce Server?

Comment: its a php/mysql shopping cart.  http://www.cs-cart.com/

Comment: I must admit i came across this bug a while ago, never thought much of it, but to this day i have no idea why this happens

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the SEO addon was the culprit.  It was doing its job correctly generating clean URLs but for some reason I couldn't load the pages.  Also, I had to disable the SSL option so I could view the cart and checkout pages to style them.  Hope this helps someone else!